# Gadfly package cannot be found?

Tags: julia, gadfly

Using Julia 0.5.0 and Emacs 25.1 on a Windows 10 machine, I am attempting to use the Gadfly package. Unfortunately, the following output appears:

```
C:\Users\CaitlinG>julia -e "using Gadfly"
ERROR: ArgumentError: Module Gadfly not found in current path.
Run `Pkg.add("Gadfly")` to install the Gadfly package.
 in require(::Symbol) at .\loading.jl:365
 in eval(::Module, ::Any) at .\boot.jl:234
 in process_options(::Base.JLOptions) at .\client.jl:239
 in _start() at .\client.jl:318

C:\Users\CaitlinG>julia -e "Pkg.add(\"Gadfly\")"
INFO: Nothing to be done
INFO: METADATA is out-of-date — you may not have the latest version of Gadfly
INFO: Use `Pkg.update()` to get the latest versions of your packages

C:\Users\CaitlinG>julia -e "Pkg.update()"
INFO: Updating METADATA...
INFO: Updating cache of DataFrames...
INFO: Updating cache of DataFrames...
INFO: Computing changes...
INFO: No packages to install, update or remove
```

Does anyone know why this is occurring?

Thanks.

Comment: Does Gadfly now appear in your REQUIRE file (c:\Users\CaitlinG\.julia\v0.5\REQUIRE) or as a folder in that directory? You may need to Pkg.add("Gadfly") one more time after the Pkg.update().

Comment: Does `using` any package work at all? say, `using DataFrames`?

Comment: HI. No, I am unable to load any package with the "using packageName" syntax.